# Devise: Authenticate with Just Username Only Instead of Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

everyone!

So I'm building an application that only needs a username for authentication and not an email.

In my config/initializers/devise.rb, I changed the :email to :username resulting to this

```
config.authentication_keys = [:username]
config.case_insensitive_keys = [:username]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:username]
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :stores
  has_many :customers, through: :stores
  has_many :visits, through: :stores
  has_many :mall_managers

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

I also edited the views accordingly.

When I try to sign up I get an error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `email' for #<User:0x000000011bd61b38>
```

Comment: does your user table contain `email` column ?

Answer (score 1):

i guess your user table does not contain `email` column, but the module `validatable` of gem `devise` will `validates_presence_of` the  `email`, so that error will be raised.

however module `validatable` allow you ignore `email validation` by override `email_required?` method

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
 # ...
 def email_required?
  false
 end

 def will_save_change_to_email?
  false
 end

 def email_changed?
  false
 end
end
```

**update** i found more 2 methods need to override (as above), and who know what else (in future versions) ? so i recommend you add `email` database field (if the root cause i suspect (miss email) correct).

Comment: Nice, I never would have guessed this, given the context provided... Lesson for OP: **please ALWAYS share the FULL(!!!!!) error message**. Don't try do be "helpful" by only showing the top line of the error; it's actually very unhelpful. I would bet good money that critical information about the root of this error is visible in the full message.